# How to check if a JS file is finished loading?

Tags: javascript

I need to enable a button when a JS file is finished loading. The JS file which I am using is a builder from WebSphere Portlet Factory (WPF). How can I check if the JS file is finished loading so that I can enable the button?

Comment: inside the js file specified, add code to hide your button.. is this using jquery?

Comment: @achusonline: We may assume that the OP has no control whatsoever over the content of the JS file being loaded (as it's part of a 3rd party framework). It has to happen externally. The answer is otherwise indeed too obvious :)

Comment: One way would be to setInterval() and check for the existence of a function or object that this file provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you loading the file?  If it's an ordinary `<script>` tag, the *next* Javascript file will not be run until all previous files have finished loading or died trying.

Other techniques (like `$.ajax`) have explicit provisions for completion callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

and Other way

```
// most browsers
scriptVar.onload = oCallback;

// IE 6 & 7
scriptVar.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
        oCallback();
    }
}
```