# fire js function when all the scripts are delivered through a CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am facing a strange problem. I have some javascript files which are loaded in some of my HTML pages. The web page is running perfectly on localhost. But when we pushed the code in the deployment server, some functionality of the page didnt work, We checked the browser console  and the errors we are getting are like this --

```
$("#scrollbar").get_scroll() is not a function
```

What we think is errors are coming due to the facts that the javascript files are not delivered at that time(through our CDN) and js function are called before the javascript files are loaded.

I was searching and found out that their is a **$(window).load** event which fires when complete page is fully loaded (see link [here](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/))

I would like to know if this event also hold itself until all the javascript files are loaded, or is their any other event in javascript which executes when all js files are loaded

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825143/how-to-check-if-a-js-file-is-finished-loading. I hope this answers your question:

Answer (score 0):

Yes, window.onload function will be called once the page is loaded completely.